# What is the significance of the Hilbert numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The [Hilbert numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_number) are natural numbers of $4n + 1$.

I've looked online for information about the Hilbert numbers and can't seem to find much about them. There's some interesting questions about Hilbert numbers that can't be expressed as the product of previous Hilbert numbers, but aside from that I can't seem to find them in any other contexts. I'm assuming that they probably appear at least *somewhere* given that David Hilbert was such a great mathematician.

What is the significance of the Hilbert numbers? Where are they commonly applied?

Comment: They don't have unique factorization...$21*33=9*77$, though none of the numbers $9,21,33,77$ can be factored within the Hilbert numbers.  Very useful for showing that certain approaches to proving unique factorization can't work.  A while ago I tried to find evidence in Hilbert's writing that he actually used them in this (or any) context, but was unsuccessful.  (of course I might have missed something).

Comment: You can always find interesting facts about sequences on OEIS https://oeis.org/A016813 . For example "Numbers n such that $\frac{1 + \sqrt n}{2}$ is an algebraic integer." or "Numbers $n$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ have the same binary digital sum."